# How to have a single asp.net mvc project with cookie authentication for mvc controllers and token authentication for API controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, access-token, cookie-authentication

We have an existing asp.net Mvc 5 application having external login with OAuth2 providers like google, and microsoft. We are using CookieAuthenticatoin for this.

Now we need to add ApiContoller to the same application.

Is there any way to use the same cookie to authenticate ApiControllers. Can I configure both cookie authentication and tokenauthentication in Startup file?